# Why is there an exception using DialogResult::OK in C++ CLI

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli

I am trying to open a picture and show it in picturebox but getting an exception.

I use visual studio 2017 c++ CLI.

I include those libraries in the beginning

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#pragma managed

#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

cv::Mat img; cv::Mat imgThresh;
```

[image]

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9582E5D43 (comctl32.dll) in LPRCNN.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFB2BEB41A.
>   occurred

```
private: System::Void btnBrowse_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        //Stream;
    Stream^ myStream;

    OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

    openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = Directory::GetCurrentDirectory();
    openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr)
        {

            file_path_temp = (openFileDialog1->FileName);
            txtImgUrl->Text = file_path_temp;

            IntPtr pointer_temp = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(file_path_temp);
            const char* input_location = static_cast<const char*>(pointer_temp.ToPointer());

            cv::Mat imgOriginalScene = cv::imread(input_location, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);

            if (!imgOriginalScene.empty())
            {
                cvtColor(imgOriginalScene, img, CV_RGB2RGBA);
                cv::imwrite("temp/temp.bmp", imgOriginalScene);
                System::Drawing::Graphics^ graphics = PicBoxCar->CreateGraphics();
                System::Drawing::Bitmap^ b = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap("temp/temp.bmp");
                System::Drawing::RectangleF rect(0, 0, (float)PicBoxCar->Width, (float)PicBoxCar->Height);
                graphics->DrawImage(b, rect);
                delete b;                   
            }
            else
                MessageBox::Show("Cannot open this image please choose another one !!", "Path:");

            myStream->Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does the exception error say? Also, please review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9582E5D43 (comctl32.dll) in LPRCNN.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFB2BEB41A. occurred

Comment: @Daniel i edit the post

Comment: Your usage of `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` is wrong.  Please use `marshal_as` instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt ty but why StringToHGlobalAnsi  is wrong

Comment: One, the function itself is broken because it does not return an `HGLOBAL` as it claims, and your usage is broken because you didn't free the memory you got.